# Random cc1 processes make my Ubuntu freeze

Tags: process

This is really weird. Sometimes, seemingly without any good reason a bunch of processes named `cc1` will pop up and consume all my CPU causing my ubuntu to nearly freeze. After 10-15 seconds those processes disappear again. Does anyone have an idea what's happening?

I googled and it seems that `cc1` has to do with the `gcc` compiler, but I'm not compiling anything. Last time it happened was after a fresh reboot with only Chrome and Terminal running (plus some background processes, such as Dropbox).

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have easy engine installed @Stan?

Answer (score 6):

This may be due to new kernels being installed on a security update and you have some drivers being built in the background by DKMS.  Can you run ps to identify any of the names of the source files being compiled?

Alternatively, install forkstat and run that to see new processes activity:

```
sudo apt install forkstat
sudo forkstat -d
```

Answer (score 6):

Check cc1 arguments (if possible)

```
ps -eF | grep cc1
```

You can try do it in loop.
Look for something like `KBUILD_MODNAME=...` or `/var/lib/dkms/...`.
In my case it was incompatible version of DisplayLink USB driver (evdi module) problem. It began using 100% of cpu after installing a new kernel. Everything started working fine after installing new drivers.

Comment: Which new drivers did you install? The evdi module is definitely causing this problem on my machine. I installed version 5.4.1 of the DisplayLink drivers from here: https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu Problem is still ongoing, though... Ubuntu 21.10 in my case.